# How to swap elements in MutableList in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, mutablelist

I have a list with data that I pull from api. However, I need to make changes on this list (movieList). I need to swap the element at index 0 with the element at index 1. For example:

> list[0] = movieA,
> list[1] = movieB

then

> list[0] = movieB,
> list[1] = movieA

The class I intend to do these operations is below:

```
data class MovieListDto(
    val docs: List<Movie>,
    val limit: Int,
    val offset: Int,
    val page: Int,
    val pages: Int,
    val total: Int
)

fun MovieListDto.MovieListDtoToMovieList(): List<Movie> {
    val movieList = mutableListOf<Movie>()

    for (movie in docs) {
        if (movie._id == "5cd95395de30eff6ebccde5c" ||
            movie._id == "5cd95395de30eff6ebccde5b" ||
            movie._id == "5cd95395de30eff6ebccde5d"
        ) {
            movieList.add(movie)
        }
    }
    return movieList
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a simple extension function for that:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int){
    val tmp = this[index1]
    this[index1] = this[index2]
    this[index2] = tmp
}
```

it can be use like this:

```
list.swap(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `also` scope function to swap

```
movieList[0] = movieList[1].also { movieList[1] = movieList[0] }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Collections.swap()` method in JDK

see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections#swap(java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Kotlin extension function, this function can be called on instances of the class.([@birneee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69937512/7756492) answer)

```
fun <E> MutableList<E>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int){
    this[index1] = this[index2].also { this[index2] = this[index1] }
}
```

or just use [also](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) scope function ([@putra-nugraha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69937113/7756492) answer)

```
list[index1] = list[index2].also { list[index2] = list[index1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val temp = movieList[0]
movieList[0] = movieList[1]
movieList[1] = temp
```

Comment: Yeah, it works of course, but I actually wanted to ask if there is a special function for this in Kotlin (my mistake).